# Updating displayed results after modifying Firestore doc React Native

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have a list of games that I'm able to add to without issue using UseEffect and onSnapshot. I can modify an item in the list without issue, and return one set of results (with the updated data properly displaying). When I try to modify another item (or the item same again), I get this error:
`Could not update game: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_doc.data().numPlayers')` because the results/list of games are null. I'm sure I have something wrong with my code, but I can't figure it out.
Thanks in advance!

Here is my code:

```
useEffect(() => {
      setIsLoading(true)
      let results = [];
      const unsubscribe = db
        .collection('games')
        .onSnapshot(
          (querySnapshot) => {  
            querySnapshot.docChanges().forEach(change => {
              const id = change.doc.id;

              if (change.type === 'added') {
                const gameData = change.doc.data();
                gameData.id = id;
                results.push(gameData);
              }
              if (change.type === 'modified') {
                console.log('Modified game: ', id);
                results = results.map(game => {
                  if (game.id === id) {
                    return change.doc.data()
                  }
                  return game
                })
                console.log(results)
              }
              if (change.type === 'removed') {
                console.log('Removed game: ', id);
              }

          });
          setIsLoading(false); 
          setGame(results);
          return () => unsubscribe
        },
        (err) => {
          setIsLoading(false);
          console.log("Data could not be fetched", err);
        }
      );
    }, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to add the doc ID to the gameData before adding it to the results. I did that in the "added" section, but not in the "modified" section (thinking that it was already included), forgetting that I hadn't added it as an actual field in the database (it just exists as the doc id).